# Medicaid long-term care applications statistics

Tags: united-states, healthcare

I am looking for statistics on applications for Medicaid long-term care coverage in the United States; ideally broken down by state, but I will take what I can get. I would like to know how many people apply each year, how many are accepted, and when applications are denied, how often is it due to the asset test, how often the disability test, etc.?

Comment: Have you tried to search online for these information?

Comment: Hard information to find but see, e.g. https://www.statista.com/statistics/245415/medicaid-spending-on-long-term-care-services-in-the-us-since-1990/ https://www.caregiver.org/resource/selected-long-term-care-statistics/ https://www.kff.org/infographic/medicaids-role-in-nursing-home-care/  https://www.medicaid.gov/medicaid/long-term-services-supports/reports-evaluations/index.html https://www.americanbar.org/groups/law_aging/publications/bifocal/vol-41/bifocal-vol-41-issue-4/nursing-home-eviction-appeals/ https://prospect.org/familycare/the-collapse-of-long-term-care-insurance/

Comment: Also references and reports in the above and reports linked at https://health.maryland.gov/mmcp/Pages/Reports-and-Publications.aspx